# Read txt files and write it in Excel format

Tags: java

I'm a newbie, but somehow my spv wants me to convert a complicated .txt(output file from a calculation software) file to excel format so it's easier to understand by others.

Here's the small part of the .txt file :

```
@BLD+@LW-1      @BLD-@   **0.99  1  g**      **46.32    102.52    158.71    101.97  0.09**

   **2** @RGB 255   0   0@@BLD+@**min**@RGB   0   0   0@@BLD-@      **0.00** @RGB 255   0   0@@BLD+@     **0.00**@RGB   0   0   0@@BLD-@      **0.00      0.00  0.00**

@RGB   0   0 255@@BLD+@**max**@RGB   0   0   0@@BLD-@      **6.92** @RGB   0   0 255@@BLD+@    **30.00**@RGB   0   0   0@@BLD-@     **53.09     29.84  0.13**
```

what I need to get is the values written in bold.

Any kind of help or at least the idea how to solve it will be very helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What part of this task is causing troubles - 1) reading a textfile and parsing its content for picking some particular information or 2) creating an excel file with extracted values? Or both?

Comment: well..I can say it's both..:)

Answer (score 0):

For reading the input, you would have to parse the input in your code

For outputting to Excel you can use either [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [JExcelApi](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to decide parsing pattern, from your example I can see that, you want to get all the values after last @ symbol plus you also want "min" and "max" and then if there is decimal values in between two @ symbols you also want those, after deciding your parsing pattern you can create a file with .csv extension and store these values as comma seperated in it as follows,

Read .txt file line by line and store it in .csv file line by line,

0.99,1g,46.32,102.52,158.71,101.97,0.09.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your txt file and create excel with [JExcel](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Each row will be converted into a row in your output file. Your values (cells) are separated by a separator (in this case a white character or character set, maybe tab). So you should read all the rows and store them into an array (after splitting the values using the separator). When you have finished doing this you can use JExcel or Apache POI to export the values.